# POST request body being lost with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy for a http service using a configuration like this:

```
location /jobexecutor/ {
        proxy_pass      http://jobexecutor:8080/jobexecutor/;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_connect_timeout   75s;
}
```

GET requests are being proxied to the service fine, but when I use POST the request is proxied to the service OK, but the body is empty. When POSTing to the service directly it works fine.
Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: @tdugeon What tech do you use to send and to receive the HTTP request?

Comment: @HatzavWolff I'm testing with curl. Exact command is:  

    curl -kL -X POST -H "Authorization: bearer $token"  -F "ExecutionParameters=@ExecutionParametersSdf.json;type=application/json;filename=ExecutionParameters.json"  -F "input=@../../../../data/testfiles/Kinase_inhibs.sdf;type=chemical/x-mdl-sdfile;filename=input"  -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed"  http://nginx/jobexecutor/rest/v1/jobs/submit-async

Comment: @tdugeon and how do you check the POST body?

Comment: In code on the receiving end. Grab the body as a String and log it.
Works fine when being accessed directly, body is empty when accessing via reverse proxy.

Comment: @tdugeon Can you please add the code to "log the string"? in addition, what does it mean "accessed directly" - by browser?

Comment: The code is using Apache Camel:  

                .post("/submit-async").description("Submit a new asynchronous job")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off)
                .outType(JobStatus.class)
                .route()
                .log("handling Job posting")
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "BODY:\n${body}")

Comment: By 'accessed directly' I mean hitting the service directly from curl, not going via the nginx proxy

Answer (score 7):

You have found a workaround, but I suspect not the root cause.

As per [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2) it's a known issue that 301 and 302 server responses often result in the conversion of request methods which are not [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) to GET requests when following the redirect.

A normal `proxy_pass` should be transparent to the client, so it sounds like some other part of your Nginx configuration is doing some client redirection first, before the request gets proxied.

Once you determine where this is happening you can either reconfigure your Nginx conf to eliminate the redirect, or change the 301/302 response codes to 307/308 respectively, which redirect while maintaining the original request method.

Comment: This. In my case (and looks likely in the OP's case too), I had 'location /whatever/' but was sending the original POST request to /whatever (no trailing slash). Browser requests /whatever, nginx returns 301, browser automatically retries at /whatever/ but changes the request method to GET.

Comment: @Burrito For me it was very similar but due to redirection from HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: OK:
location ^~ /api/v2/aaa/bbb/cccc {
    proxy_pass http://test_server//api/v2/aaa/bbb/cccc;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
 }
NOT OK:
 location ^~ /api/v2/aaa/bbb/cccc/ {
    proxy_pass http://test_server//api/v2/aaa/bbb/cccc/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
 }

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer to this. The problem was with curl, in that when following a redirect it wants to convert the POST into a GET, but the `-X` arg seems to force it to keep it as a GET, but the body get's lost.
To get the expected behaviour you need to specify the `--post301` or similar argument (as well as the `-L` argument).
See https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--post301