# Request body is not passing in http url but it is present in https url

Tags: nginx

I am testing some APIs with POSTMAN.

When i am sending data in request body (raw section in POSTMAN) , data is present when i call the url with https i.e `https://example.com/api-url/` but i am receiving empty body when i send the request with http url i.e `http://example.com/api-url/`

Non-secure requests are working fine. They are being directed to https. Only issue is request body is not being there when any request is called from http url.

**What is wrong in nginx configuration?**

This is the nginx configuration.

```
server {
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return       301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        client_max_body_size 4G;

        access_log /home/myuser/myproject/logs/nginx-access.log;
        error_log /home/myuser/myproject/logs/nginx-error.log;

        server_name example.com ;
        
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors *.exampledomain.com" always;

        location /static/ {  alias   /home/myuser/myproject/staticfiles/; }    
        location /media/ {  alias   /home/myuser/myproject/media/; }

        

        location / {
                     proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myuser/myvenv/myproject/daphne.sock;
                     proxy_http_version 1.1;
                     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                     proxy_redirect     off;
                     proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                     proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                     proxy_read_timeout 240;
                     proxy_connect_timeout 240;
                     proxy_send_timeout 240;
                     send_timeout 240;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name example.com ;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name  www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52557602/10585627) by @miknik . It states that there is an issue while redirecting with 301/302 status codes. I replaced 301 with 307 in my nginx configuration and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Express body-parser/json-parser didn't parse the body when you call with http, and did not pass it to `req.body`.
Add this into your / proxy handler May correct your problem :

```
                 proxy_set_header content-type "application/json";
```

like this :

```
    location / {
                 proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myuser/myvenv/myproject/daphne.sock;
                 proxy_http_version 1.1;
                 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                 proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                 proxy_set_header content-type "application/json";
                 proxy_redirect     off;
                 proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                 proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                 proxy_read_timeout 240;
                 proxy_connect_timeout 240;
                 proxy_send_timeout 240;
                 send_timeout 240;
    }
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I load body in python using ```reqBody = json.loads(request.body)``` but it is giving me error ```JSONDecodeError```. I logged the request body. It is empty string i.e b''

Comment: Can you please check what else can be done? I just called with https url again to verify, code worked, But request body is empty in case of http url.